# Scala: Safe access to index in a List[DataFrame]

Tags: scala, list, dataframe, indexing

I receive a `List[DataFrame]` and I want to store each df in a variable. Some values always exist in the list:

```
val routes = dataframes(0)
val stops = dataframes(1)
```

But other ones may also come so the size list is variable.
How could I perform a safely access to a index of list that may be out of bounds? I thought that with `Some()` and handling the result it would works:

```
val fare_attributes : Option[DataFrame] = Some(dataframes(10))

fare_attributes match {
      case Some(fare) =>  upload())
        println("fare_attributes uploaded")

      case None => println("No fare_attributes found")
    }
```

But I receive: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.lift` on your list:

```
val fare_attributes : Option[DataFrame] = dataframes.lift(10)
```

Comment: As a bit of additional explanation for why it works, `lift` is a method on `PartialFunction[A, B]` that returns an `A => Option[B]`, and `List[A]` extends from `PartialFunction[Int, A]` (so it has the `lift` method). So you're effectively calling `dataframes.lift.apply(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to rely on checking the length of the list before accessing the indexed value. You may want to implement some wrapper function to do so. So that it isn't done repeatedly.

You can be a bit "elegant" about it with **currying** with two parameter lists. So that your code is a bit concise. Here's a sample which you may improve.

```
def safeList(list: List[Int])(index: Int): Int = {
  if (index < list.length) list(index)
  else 0
}

val x = List(1, 2 ,3 )
val y = safeList(x)(_)

val a = y(0) // returns 1
val b = y(1) // returns 2
val c = y(4) // returns 0
```